# Excel: How can I pair particular rows and then sort?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a sheet that has inventory for particular things. In the inventory list I have a box that contains a variety of materials.

I want to be able to organize my excel spreadsheet such that the box name appears as (almost) a title with the stuff in it as sub-rows. Then I want to sort based on the box name with the other items in the inventory, just based on the item.

[image: This is what I am talking about]

Comment: how your source data looks like? How Excel should now that "Coffee box" is the category and the others are the sub-categories?

Answer (score 4):

Rule #1 for maintaining sanity in Excel is to separate **presentation** from **data**. Here's one suggestion on how to organize your information, which I would place in a sheet called ('Data')

[image]

Notice that I've selected the range and highlighted where you click to create a Pivot Table, which is your next step.

After you click 'Ok' in the Pivot Table dialog, you'll need to place your fields in their respective positions. Here's one tentative layout, but feel free to play around to find what suits you best:

[image]